# How to get elliptical corners with css to get a "flower petal shape"

Tags: css

I was wondering how to convert this shape to css.

[image]

my attempt at it is not so accurate:

https://codepen.io/glooxbox/pen/KKZywQy

```
#box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 60% 60% 4% 60%;
}
```

Comment: Your codepen seems fine to me... which part is wrong?

Comment: I need the code to exactly match the image. what's wrong is the bottom right part. I can't adjust the border-radius to match that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set `top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left`. This is used to set an additional radius which allows you to  have elliptical corners.

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  /* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left */
  border-radius: 60% 60% 10% 60% / 60% 60% 60% 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">

</div>
```

This will work `border-radius: 60% 60% 10% 60% / 60%;`. See [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)